# JAX-RS web service is working on GlassFish Server 4.0 but not working on Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, api, jax-rs, restful-architecture

I am new to web services. So I started with a small program like the following.

It's working perfectly in GlassFish server but not in Tomcat (I want to run on Tomcat). It's a simple program which gives only the idea of how to run the web service application.

FirstRestService.java:

```
package com.sandy.demo;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/resources")
public class FirstRestService extends Application {

}
```

Employees.java:

```
package com.sandy.demo;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/employees")
public class Employees {

    @GET
    public String getEmployeesNames() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I have included the `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar` (JAX-RS API JAR file).

I took a working WAR file of the application and deployed in GlassFish Server. Then I ran the server with the URL: `http://localhost:8080/MyFirstRestApplication/resources/employees`.

But I am unable to do the same in Tomcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar` refers to [JAX-RS 1.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311). GlassFish Server 4.0 uses [JAX-RS 2.0](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339).

Besides the correct JAX-RS dependency JAR, you'll need a JAX-RS implementation such as [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) (used by [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/)) or [RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) (used by [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/)).

GlassFish already contains all JAX-RS 2.0 and Jersey dependencies you need. Tomcat doesn't.

Since you were using GlassFish, probably you'll choose Jersey. There are two ways to include JAX-RS and Jersey in your Tomcat project:

### 1. Using Maven

If you are using Maven, add the following dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, 
         use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Required only when you are using JAX-RS Client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Just ensure you are using the correct `artifactId` according to your Tomcat Servlet API version: if your Tomcat implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use [`jersey-container-servlet-core`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-container-servlet-core/dependencies.html). Otherwise, use [`jersey-container-servlet`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.22.1/jersey/project/jersey-container-servlet/dependencies.html).

On [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) you'll find information about the Servlet API version used by each Tomcat version. To summarize:

- Tomcat 8.0.x: Servlet API 3.1
- Tomcat 7.0.x: Servlet API 3.0
- Tomcat 6.0.x: Servlet API 2.5

The latest version of each `artifactId` can be checked in the Maven Repository:

- [`jersey-container-servlet-core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core)
- [`jersey-container-servlet`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet)

See more information about Jersey dependencies on the [documentation page](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html).

### 2. Manually downloading JAX-RS and Jersey dependencies

If you are not using Maven, refer to [Jersey download page](https://jersey.java.net/download.html), download the *Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle* and include the dependencies on the classpath.

The *Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle* contains the JAX-RS 2.0 API JAR, all the core Jersey module JARs as well as all the required 3rd-party dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I have added the required jar files manually. Now the application is deployed on tomcat.

Comment: @sandy  If the answer was useful, please consider upvoting and accepting it.